# API queries in ngOnInit are executed from previous component

Tags: angular

I have
`signin.component.ts`:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.metaService.getMetaCompany().subscribe((response: Json) => {
      console.log('meta company');
    });
  }
```

and `app.component.ts`:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    if (authenticated) {
     this.metaService.getMetaCompany().subscribe((response: Json) => {
       console.log('meta company');
     });
   }
  }
```

`meta.service.ts`:

```
getMetaCompany(): Observable<Json | JsonError> {
 return this.http
  .get<Json | JsonError>(this.getMetaCompanyUrl)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.errorService.handleError)
 );
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signin', loadChildren: () => import('./signin/signin.module').then(m => m.SignInModule) },
  { path: 'inbox', loadChildren: () => import('./inbox/inbox.module').then(m => m.InboxModule) },
  { path: 'work', loadChildren: () => import('./work/work.module').then(m => m.WorkModule) },
  { path: 'something-went-wrong', component: InternalServerErrorComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Redirection I execute with using these commands:

from sign out to sign in:

```
this.router.navigate(['signin'], { queryParams: { r: this.sharedService.currentUrl }});
```

from signin to another:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
```

When I'm on sign in page it's executed API query once, everything is fine, but after successful login I redirected to another page and in console log I see API query is executed twice: from `app.component` and `signin.component`.

I can't understand why I see queries from previous component (signin).
The same situation with sign out. I'm sign out and redirect to login page but API requests from `ngOnInit` of any previous component (it doesn't depend on page) are executed for some reasons and I'm getting errors because user was already signed out. Everything works fine between pages/components when user was logged in.

So how can I avoid executing API queries from previous component?

Comment: Is SIgnInComponent inside AppComponent ? (or in a root depending of AppComponent ?

Comment: SignInComponent inside AppComponent

Comment: And how do you redirect? With href ?

Comment: No
from sign out to sign in -> `this.router.navigate(['signin'], { queryParams: { r: this.sharedService.currentUrl }});`
from signin to another -> `this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);`

Comment: And for `getMetaCompany`,  is it a direct http call? (I ask in case you need to unsubscribe to the observable)

Comment: updated question with service method

Comment: Can you show us your route configuration ?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy, Added the answer, hope it'll work for you.

Comment: @ZellB. what do you mean under route configuration?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy the routes array that your app uses. Typically registered on app module RouterModule import.

Comment: @ZellB. updated question with route configuration

Comment: Where is app component declared in the route array ?

Comment: nowhere, it's in `app.module.ts` only (updated question with app module)

Answer (score 1):

This is called as Memory Leakage by Api Subscription,

The best practice is to destroy your subscription in current component before you navigate to other component.

Follow the steps to do the same.

1. Add the Subject from 'rxjs/internal/Subject' just before the constructor.

   `destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();`
2. Add the below pipe to every api call before subscription

   `.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))`
3. And finally implement the OnDestory hook with destroying all above subscription.

   `ngOnDestroy(): void { this.destroy$.next(true); this.destroy$.unsubscribe(); }`